# Authenticating against Earth Search API or STAC API to get raster images

Tags: raster, amazon-s3, stac

I'm fairly new to the GIS domain and must query the Earth Search API to get some imagery. these endpoints do not require authentication:

`https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0/search`

`https://sat-api.developmentseed.org/stac/search`

however, if I try to access any URLs in the assets of certain features I receive a 403 unauthorized. I couldn't find any documentation as to how I'm supposed to authenticate to retrieve the images.

for example, I run this query:

```
curl --location 'https://sat-api.developmentseed.org/stac/search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     7.163171768188476,
                     50.01584714780868
                  ],
                  [
                     7.1739864349365225,
                     50.01584714780868
                  ],
                  [
                     7.1739864349365225,
                     50.01970768279515
                  ],
                  [
                     7.163171768188476,
                     50.01970768279515
                  ],
                  [
                     7.163171768188476,
                     50.01584714780868
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}'
```

and get the following response

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "limit": 10,
        "found": 20420366,
        "returned": 10
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "S2B_36JVQ_20220922_1",
            "bbox": [
                32.49789531072767,
                -27.233993420869517,
                33.098566762203674,
                -27.121581200473422
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            33.098566762203674,
                            -27.233993420869517
                        ],
                        [
                            32.49789531072767,
                            -27.121581200473422
                        ],
                        [
                            33.09846880258467,
                            -27.12244415341007
                        ],
                        [
                            33.098566762203674,
                            -27.233993420869517
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "collection": "sentinel-2-l1c",
                "eo:gsd": 10,
                "eo:instrument": "MSI",
                "eo:off_nadir": 0,
                "eo:bands": [
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.027,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.4439,
                        "name": "B01",
                        "gsd": 60,
                        "common_name": "coastal"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.098,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.4966,
                        "name": "B02",
                        "gsd": 10,
                        "common_name": "blue"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.045,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.56,
                        "name": "B03",
                        "gsd": 10,
                        "common_name": "green"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.038,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.6645,
                        "name": "B04",
                        "gsd": 10,
                        "common_name": "red"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.019,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.7039,
                        "name": "B05",
                        "gsd": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.018,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.7402,
                        "name": "B06",
                        "gsd": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.028,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.7825,
                        "name": "B07",
                        "gsd": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.145,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.8351,
                        "name": "B08",
                        "gsd": 10,
                        "common_name": "nir"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.033,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.8648,
                        "name": "B8A",
                        "gsd": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.026,
                        "center_wavelength": 0.945,
                        "name": "B09",
                        "gsd": 60
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.075,
                        "center_wavelength": 1.3735,
                        "name": "B10",
                        "gsd": 60,
                        "common_name": "cirrus"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.143,
                        "center_wavelength": 1.6137,
                        "name": "B11",
                        "gsd": 20,
                        "common_name": "swir16"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_width_half_max": 0.242,
                        "center_wavelength": 2.22024,
                        "name": "B12",
                        "gsd": 20,
                        "common_name": "swir22"
                    }
                ],
                "datetime": "2022-09-22T07:57:38.703000+00:00",
                "eo:platform": "sentinel-2b",
                "eo:cloud_cover": 0,
                "sentinel:utm_zone": 36,
                "sentinel:latitude_band": "J",
                "sentinel:grid_square": "VQ",
                "sentinel:sequence": "1",
                "sentinel:product_id": "S2B_MSIL1C_20220922T072619_N0400_R049_T36JVQ_20220922T093016"
            },
            "assets": {
                "B02": {
                    "title": "Band 2 (blue)",
                    "type": "image/jp2",
                    "eo:bands": [
                        2
                    ],
                    "href": "https://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/36/J/VQ/2022/9/22/1/B02.jp2"
                },
            },
        }
    ],
}
```

and the image URL `https://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/36/J/VQ/2022/9/22/1/B02.jp2`
gives me a 403 unauthorized.

How do I access this image?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

[Sentinel 2 on AWS](https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2/) is [requester pays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RequesterPaysBuckets.html).

> In general, bucket owners pay for all Amazon S3 storage and data transfer costs that are associated with their bucket. However, you can configure a bucket to be a Requester Pays bucket. With Requester Pays buckets, the requester instead of the bucket owner pays the cost of the request and the data download from the bucket. The bucket owner always pays the cost of storing data.

The data is free, but AWS charges for data transfer and "requester pays" allows the data owner to pass the transfer cost to the user.

Once you have an AWS account that can be billed, you can [access the data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ObjectsinRequesterPaysBuckets.html) using the REST API, AWS CLI or one of a number of geospatial libraries that support authenticated access to AWS such as GDAL or rasterio.